# Simplify a vector 3x3: { expression1(t), expression2(t), expression3(t) }

Tags: list-manipulation, simplifying-expressions

For example, I have this: {36 t, -36 t^2, -18}. There is a way to obtain this {2 t, -2 t^2, -1}*18   automatically?

Comment: By default, the factor (`18`) would always be pulled back into the list in the output. So you have to prevent the output from being evaluated as an expression, or make it inactive. What kind of output format are you looking for? Maybe a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the intended meaning of "Simplify" in this case is to factor out common integer divisors, then you could do this:

```
list = {36 t, -36 t^2, -18};

Row[{#, list/#}] &[PolynomialGCD @@ list]
```

> $18\{2 t, -2 t^2, -1\}$

Here I used [`PolynomialGCD`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PolynomialGCD.html) to pull out the factor `18`. For the output, I chose [`Row`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Row.html) because in a standard math expression the multiplication by a prefactor would by default be threaded over the `List`, leading back to the original input expression.

Comment: This will work also in order to factor out common divisors that are not integers?

Comment: No, you'll have to do that by hand because there's no unique way to determine what you would like to factor out. You could probably do fancier stuff with `Rationalize` to pull out certain non-integer numbers but I don't know what your use case actually is.

Comment: I have one problem. As you can see:

Comment: I have one problem. As you can see:
In[201]:= g1etg2etg1

Out[201]= {54 - 216 t^4, -108 (t + 2 t^3), 108 (t + 2 t^3)}

In[202]:= Row[{#, g1etg2etg1/#}] &[PolynomialGCD @@ g1etg2etg1]

Out[202]= Row[{54 + 108 t^2, {(54 - 216 t^4)/(
   54 + 108 t^2), -((108 (t + 2 t^3))/(54 + 108 t^2)), (
   108 (t + 2 t^3))/(54 + 108 t^2)}}]

I have this. But what I need is only to factor out 54 from {54 - 216 t^4, -108 (t + 2 t^3), 108 (t + 2 t^3)}

Comment: I don't know how to show you the output with a picture. How to add picture in the comment?

Comment: I would suggest editing the question.